# Telling .map to skip over an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

In the following code maps over a `useState` called `allTodos`. It uses this data to render multiple components:

```
let todoComponents = allTodos.map(item => <Todos key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={handleChange}/>)
```

The problem is that the `.map` needs access the `id` in an object within an object with a unique name.
[image]

How can I tell `.map` to skip over the object, regardless of its name and get the `id`(other any other values).

Comment: You can return null in map callback or use filter() but not really clear what your conditions are. Explanation is a bit circular and could use some more specifics to clarify

Comment: Filter the data and then do the mapping

Comment: Perhaps `Object.keys(allTodos[0]).map(id => allTodos[id])`?

Comment: @charlietfl Condition: It needs to return the value of `id`. However, I'm trying to direct the function on where to get this value. In the same way that in HTML one can use "./../whatever" to tell the program to get the file of "whatever.js" regardless of it's location.

Comment: That seems like a completely different issue than "skip in map()". Also still a bit confusing

Comment: @charlietfl Check out the first example: `{m8CpkuPCNu0_Eajituu: {completed: fals..}`. I trying to return an arrary removing the data from inside that. It should instead return `{completed: fals..}`

Comment: @charlietfl I posted more clear question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026178/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-nested-object-with-unknown-paths)

Answer (score 1):

filter then map

```
allTodos.filter(i=> !i.completed).map(...)
```

Comment: Is the `(...)` code that I am supposed add or is it a shortening?

Comment: yes, it's this code : `item => <Todos key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={handleChange}/>`

Comment: Check out the first example: `{m8CpkuPCNu0_Eajituu: {completed: fals..}`. I trying to return an arrary removing the data from inside that. It should instead return `{completed: fals..}`