# How to get the value of a nested object with unknown paths?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Originally, I was rendering components by using this code to map an array of objects( `[{}, {}, {}]` ):

```
let todoComponents = allTodos.map(item => <Todos key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={handleChange}/>)
```

[image]

However, this does not work on a separate project where I am getting data from Firebase with a different data structure. In it, each object has a unique name.

```
[{
  "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW" : {
    "completed" : false,
    "id" : "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW",
    "text" : "Get Comic Book"
  },
  "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu" : {
    "completed" : false,
    "id" : "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu",
    "text" : "Take out Trash"
  }
}]
```

The problem is that `.map` doesn't know where to look for the value of `item`. In the first example, `.map` looked for an array -> object(with values). This doesn't work for the data from firebase because array -> object -> object(with values). How can I tell `.map` to skip over the extra object without know the exact path in the nested object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is to convert:

> ```
> [{
>   "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW" : {
>     "completed" : false,
>     "id" : "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW",
>     "text" : "Get Comic Book"
>   },
>   "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu" : {
>     "completed" : false,
>     "id" : "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu",
>     "text" : "Take out Trash"
>   }
> }]
> ```

To:

```
[{
  "completed" : false,
  "id" : "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW",
  "text" : "Get Comic Book"
}, {
  "completed" : false,
  "id" : "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu",
  "text" : "Take out Trash"
}]
```

You can do so with a combination of [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
allTodos = allTodos.flatMap(todos => Object.values(todos));
```

Or if `allTodos` always contains a single object with todos you could do:

```
allTodos = Object.values(allTodos[0]);
```

After converting the data structure you can then execute your statement:

> ```
> let todoComponents = allTodos.map(item => <Todos key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={handleChange}/>)
> ```

Comment: How would you convert it back to a unflatten array?

Comment: By not flatting it in the first place. Use `map` instead of `flatMap` to keep the nested array.

Comment: I flattened the array because `.map` couldn't get the request value, but now I can't use firebase's `.set` method to update my database because it doesn't use the new data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the object that you got from firebase let's say data then:

```
const obj = data[0]; // i am assuming there is only one object in the array
const allTodos = Object.values(obj); // allTodos is now an array of todos and you can use your original code
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps!

```js
let data = [{
  "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW": {
    "completed": false,
    "id": "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW",
    "text": "Get Comic Book"
  },
  "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu": {
    "completed": false,
    "id": "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu",
    "text": "Take out Trash"
  }
}]

data.map(ele => {
   let keys = Object.keys(ele);
   
   keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log("item is", ele[key])
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const data = [{
  "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW": {
    "completed": false,
    "id": "-M8CpcbvDriZpw4sc4IW",
    "text": "Get Comic Book"
  },
  "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu": {
    "completed": false,
    "id": "-M8Cpku0PCNu0_Eajtuu",
    "text": "Take out Trash"
  }
}];

const todoList = [];
Object.keys(data[0]).forEach( key => todoList.push(data[0][key]));
console.log(todoList)
```